# Variable amount of checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have an ArrayList of Student objects that have String name and a boolean absent,
When I open up the program I want it to use the ArrayList to create a variable amount of checkboxes dependent on how many students there are. I tried a for each loop that would create a new checkbox for every student but that crashed the entire program.

Here is the class with the GUI view

```
public class SchedulerView extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private String[] shownames = {"show1","show2"};

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static ArrayList<Student> studentlist1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    private static ArrayList<Song> songlist1 = new ArrayList<Song>();

    private static int show;

    public SchedulerView() 
    {

        setTitle("School of Rock Scheduler");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblSelectShow = new JLabel("Select Show:");
        lblSelectShow.setBounds(77, 11, 107, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSelectShow);

        JComboBox showlist = new JComboBox(shownames);
        showlist.setSelectedIndex(0);
        showlist.addActionListener(this);
        showlist.setBounds(184, 8, 149, 20);
        contentPane.add(showlist);

        for(Student student:studentlist1)
        {
            JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(Student.getName(student));
            chbx.setBounds(19, 60, 97, 23);
            contentPane.add(chbx);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        int i = cb.getSelectedIndex();
        show = i;
        System.out.println(show);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Song song1 = new Song("Holiday", false);
        Song song2 = new Song("Boulevard of Broken Dreams", false);
        Song song3 = new Song("Learn to Fly", false);
        Song song4 = new Song("Come As You Are", false);
        Song song5 = new Song("Everlong", false);

        songlist1.add(song1);songlist1.add(song2);
        songlist1.add(song3);songlist1.add(song4);
        songlist1.add(song5);

        Student student1 = new Student("Dustin",false,song1);
        Student student2 = new Student("Deloris",false,song2);
        Student student3 = new Student("Gianna",false,song3);
        Student student4 = new Student("Kelly",false,song4);
        Student student5 = new Student("Reggie",false,song5);

        studentlist1.add(student1);studentlist1.add(student2);
        studentlist1.add(student3);studentlist1.add(student4);
        studentlist1.add(student5);

        Schedule.createSchedule(studentlist1, songlist1);



        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SchedulerView frame = new SchedulerView();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get when you tried the for each loop that crashed the program? It would be useful to see the stack trace for that.

Comment: I received a stack over flow error, i updated the code on the original post to reflect what i had tried to do.

Comment: What was on the stack when it overflowed? That `for-each` loop shouldn't cause it.

Comment: Stackoverflow exception is normally caused by an infinite recursive loop. Check for something that's doing something recursively in your code to add checkboxes. An eventhandler could also cause it, if the handler retriggers the same event to occur. Make sure you do all of your UI building code BEFORE you add any event handlers. After that, the code should handle the events normally.

Comment: The for loop doesnt produce any errors now, but there is only one checkbox with the last object in the list

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)? Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify